# Too many tags by copying and pasting

Tags: discussion, tags

### Image:

I was just asking a new question on SO and ran into this:

[image: too many tags]

### Bug

- Added too many tags and can't "scroll left"
- In order to delete, I have to delete them one at a time from far left

### How to reproduce:

- Copy and paste plenty of text ("on accident")

I accidentally had a "code snippet" on my clipboard and pasted it in the "Tags" field. The "Tags" field created new tags for the paste code but then it was forced to the far left and was hidden from the current view.

### Temporary solution:

I had to delete everything one by one and then manually add some of the tags back or simply create a new question and copy everything over.

Comment: You can use the keyboard arrow and home/end keys to scroll through the tags too. On Mac, ALT-arrowkey lets you jump by word (tag) boundaries, I'm sure other platforms have similar shortcuts.

Comment: Home/End/arrow-keys still work as they should, so no problem.

Comment: Ah, here comes the negatives. I was not trying to break anything. I was not sure if anyone ran into this issue as well. @MartijnPieters Thanks.

Comment: @JaredBurrows: sorry, I was offering a work-around. Where did you see negatives in my comment?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, not you, my points. You have always been helpful!

Comment: @JaredBurrows: good thing Meta votes don't cost you points then!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I hardly ask questions on SO. I didn't know ha. It would be nice to have it "keep to the right".

Comment: @MartijnPieters: On Windows, Ctrl-arrows work well, and even Ctrl-BkSp and Ctrl-Del to delete a word at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### BUG
>
> - Added too many tags and can't "scroll left"

What do you actually mean by *can't "scroll left"*?

You can use a keyboard shortcut like <kbd>CTRL + Pos1</kbd> (as it's at least marked at my keyboard, yours might have different marks like <kbd>CTRL + Home</kbd>).

Also the arrow key <kbd><</kbd> allows you to *scroll left*, or you can use <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> as you mentioned yourself.

> - In order to delete, I have to delete them one at a time from far left

You don't need to usually.

A sequence of key presses like

<kbd>CTRL + Pos1</kbd>
<kbd>SHIFT + End</kbd>
<kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>

will clear the edit box, and lets you start over entering your intended tags.

Comment: Thank you, I just tested this out. Thanks for your comments as well.